# how to change drawerlayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement a drawer with some search conditions,like if I click one button, the drawer will be redirect to another page and continue let you to select, but I donot know how to implement, I plan to make several fragments into drawerlayout, but I donot know how to switch? I have searched a lot on Internet, the examples is to change the fragment in content, I want change the frament within the drawer.

can somebody enlighten me? great thanks!

Comment: What do you want exactly

Comment: I'm sorry confused you. what I want is a drawer, when you click one item in this drawerlayout, the drawer change its layout, and let you can click another item, like a wizard...

Comment: Can you illustrate with images so that i can understand